# How can I get parent state for child pages in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm developing a contact form and I want to develop it like the following page.
https://ubie.app/

So, I created _app.js as the parent page and step1.js, step2.js as children pages.

```
- _app.js...Parent page
- contact
+- step1.js...Child page1(Store current state to parent page)
+- step2.js...Child page2(Get current parent state)
```

Could you tell me how can I show the parent state on the child page2?
I don't know how can I get it.
I saw the following page and understood how to set state, but not sure how to get state from the parent.
[How can I pass data in multi-step forms in NextJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66267441/how-can-i-pass-data-in-multi-step-forms-in-nextjs)

_app.js

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { useState } from "react"

const AppComponent = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const updateFormData = (newData) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, ...newData });
  };
  return <Component {...pageProps} updateFormData={updateFormData} formData={formData} />;
};

export default AppComponent;
```

step1.js

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Step1({ updateFormData }) {
    const router = useRouter()
    const handleNameChange = (event) => {
        updateFormData({ name: event.target.value });
    };
    const handleSurNameChange = (event) => {
        updateFormData({ surname: event.target.value });
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                Name: <input name="name" onChange={handleNameChange} />
            </p>
            <p>
                SurName: <input name="surname" onChange={handleSurNameChange} />
            </p>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => router.push("step2")}>
                Next
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Step1;
```

step2.js

```
function Step2({formData}) {
    return (
        <>
            <p>
                {formData}
            </p>
        </>
    );
}

export default Step2;
```

Comment: What's the issue with your code? What's not working?

Comment: @juliomalves The issue is,  step2.js doesn't show "formData".
It shows just empty page

Comment: What does it show? Do you get an error? `formData` is an object so you can't render it directly. Try using `<p>{JSON.stringify(formData)}</p>` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you so much! The problem is exact same as what you mentioned.

Comment: The problem is solved?

Comment: @Sweta Jain Thank you for fixing!

Comment: @ShayanFaghani Yes, it is!